# app = xlwings.App(visible=False) raise error pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567

Tags: python, xlwings

When I set "visible=False" like this

```
import xlwings
app = xlwings.App(visible=False,add_book=False)
book = app.books.open(r'C:\Users\WT5\Desktop\xxx.xlsx')
a = [sht.name for sht in book.sheets]
print('book.sheets: ', type(book.sheets))
print(a)
book.save()
book.app.quit()
```

It comes out errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 466, in __call__
    return Book(xl=self.xl(name_or_index))
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 156, in __call__
    v = self._inner(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8.py", line 39136, in __call__
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (13, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

With "visible=True", it is OK.
Why is "visible=False" not working?
Windows 10 (64bit), python 3.8.8, xlwings 0.23, excel 2013 pro

Comment: Does it work with `add_book=True`?

Comment: Yes, it works with "add_book=True".

Comment: In theory, xlwings needs at least 1 book open to be able to communicate with Excel...I'll open an issue to handle this better.

Comment: I mean it works with "visible=True, add_book=True" but not with "visible=False, add_book=True". This happens in one computer but not in the other computer. These two computers have the same python configuration and develope environment, i.e. Windows 10 (64bit), python 3.8.8, xlwings 0.23, excel 2013 pro.